# SQLite - NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: sql, sqlite, constraints

I am trying to create a simple SQLite database that will allow me to store email addresses and timestamps.  I have created the table like this:

```
$sql =<<<EOF
        CREATE TABLE ENTRIES
        (ID INT PRIMARY KEY      NOT NULL,
        EMAIL           EMAIL    NOT NULL,
        TIMESTAMP DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
EOF;
```

And I am trying to insert an email like this:

```
$sql =<<<EOF
      INSERT INTO ENTRIES (EMAIL)
      VALUES (test@test.com);
EOF;
```

I am getting an error

> ```
> NOT NULL constraint failed: ENTRIES.ID
> ```

I am assuming this is to do with the ID and autoincrement?  I have read the docs and it advises against using autoincrement. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The docs](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) say:

> If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the ROWID.

And because it becomes an alias for the ROWID, it's not necessary to explicitly specify a value.

You have `INT PRIMARY KEY`, not `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. If you change it to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it works the way you expect.

Comment: My answer was untested.  Just pointing out problems which I saw +1.